# What is "neighbors" parameter in predict.cubist function, in R?

Tags: r, analytics, predict

I tried using **neighbors** parameter in predict function for a Cubist tree. It should be an integer from 0-9. The computed R-Square is increasing as the neighbors are nearing 0. But when neighbors is set to 0(default value), the R-Square is again low. What is "neighbors"? Why this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[Applied Predictive Modeling](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/) provides a good overview of Cubist. From their description, it's a way of adjusting the final model based on the K nearest neighbors from the training set.

It's probably best to treat it as another parameter that you need to CV.

Answer (score 0):

> The computed R-Square is increasing as the neighbors are nearing 0. But when neighbors is set to 0(default value), the R-Square is again low.

The R-Square is not the metrics used for choose the best model, as Tchotchke said, we should do cv to choose the best parameters, using the RMSE as the metrics. The following result is choose the best parameters by cv:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
cTune <- train(x = train_data[,-1], y = train_data[,1],
              "cubist",
              tuneGrid = expand.grid(committees = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
                                       neighbors = c(0, 1, 2, 3)),
              trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
cTune
```

[cTune result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o2Dn.png)

```
plot(cTune)
```

As you can see the result, zero neighbor did not get the best R-square, but the best RMSE. So the final best parameter is choose five committees and zero neighbors.

> What is "neighbors"? Why this behavior?

[neighbors correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4gG4.png)

Neighbors is just the training set which nearest the testing samples.
If there is a trend in the dependent variable, then the neighbor's behavior is used to correction the prediction error (the real tl and predicted tl term in the upper plot), if this error is very low, then neighbors can be zero.